# How to load product on button click in HTML table using KnockoutJS in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

Basically i want to load product on button click using KnockoutJS.

Comment: You want to redirect browser to product page? If not can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Basically i want to create a page.On that page there is a button ,by clicking on button every time a new product is load in table

Answer (score 0):

use magento2 Sections with knockout js
[MAGENTO2 SECTIONS](https://webkul.com/blog/sections-magento-2/)